# conditional checking of a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np
y = [1.25, 2.59, -4.87, 6.82, -7.98, -11.23]

if(np.any(y) < -10):
    print("yes")
```

> I want to check whether in a list any value below or above a
> particular value exists or not. So, I proceed with np.any(), code is
> getting compiled but not working as wished, I mean not printing back
> "yes".

Answer (score 6):

`any` should be after the brackets, and `y` should be a `numpy` array.

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array([1.25, 2.59, -4.87, 6.82, -7.98, -11.23])

if (y < -10).any():
    print("yes")
```

Comment: Yes. It has worked. Thanks. However, since I don't know the difference in y= np.array([.....]) and y = [...], could you explain this one !

Comment: `y=np.array([])` creates a `numpy` array, while `y = [...]` creates a list. A list is a built-in data type in python used to store values. A `numpy` array is from the module `numpy` and can be used with certain math operations.

Comment: if (y < -10).any(2):
    print("yes").                 Would it then be used as "if 2 of the numbers of the array are less than -10 then print yes" ??

Comment: No, but you can achieve this with sum: 
```if sum((y < -10))==2:
    print("yes")```

Answer (score 1):

`np.any()` returns a bool and you cannot compare it with an int.

it's like doing `true/false < -10`

The correct use of np.any() would be as follows:

```
(y < -10).any()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
y = [1.25, 2.59, -4.87, 6.82, -7.98, -11.23]

for value in y:
    if value < -10:
        print(f'yes there is {value} less than -10')
```

Your Output

### yes there is -11.23 less than -10

Comment: print(f 'yes there is {value} less than -10')
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: it is showing the above mentioned error, could you please help me in sorting this !

Comment: yes use print(f'yes there is {value} less than -10'). Sorry there is no space between f string in print. This works perfectly. Thank you for asking Subhadip.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
import numpy as np
y1 = np.array([1.25, 2.59, -4.87, 6.82, -7.98, -11.23])
y2 = np.array([1.25, 2.59, 4.87, 6.82, 7.98, 11.23])

if(np.any(y1 < -10)):
    print("yes y1")
else:
    print("no y1")

if(np.any(y2 < -10)):
    print("yes y2")
else:
    print("no y2")
```

Other option will be to not use numpy module, and just to scan the array elements one by one.

Comment: Yes.This is also working quite well. Thanks.

Comment: Sir, What if I want to check, say, any 2 of the numbers of an array is greater than +5.0 ! Would it be possible using this any() function ?